# Promotion T-shirts

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Thinking about how to promote Musical Practice & Performance, I remembered that a few people over at the Theoretical Computer Science SE had [this great idea about promoting their website using t-shirts](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/promotion-t-shirt-design).

I have a feeling that this could work very well for this website. Many of us often go to concerts, which are attended by quite a lot of people. Not the whole audience consists of musicians of course, far from it, but these are great opportunities to promote the website at next to no cost. Besides, I often get the chance to talk to the performing artists, and I will do my best to try and convince them to pay us a visit. If this can help bring here more expert people, and to [generate more expert questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/promotion-t-shirt-design), it would be a good thing.

So, should we get started on design ideas for those?

- let us stick to one proposal per answer (back and front), so that the most popular end up on top;
- remember that the URL should be readable from a distance;
- if you have suggestions for websites that allow you to print and ship those t-shirts, please provide them too; I already know [Cafepress](http://www.cafepress.com/), but I don't know how they compare to alternatives.

Comment: This short URL could possibly be used: [http://j.mp/musicSE](http://j.mp/musicSE)

Comment: I'm not convinced by the short URL idea...

Comment: Perhaps this would make more sense after we have a site design and logo.

Comment: @Matthew - I disagree. Short URLs can go away, and there's [a host of reasons why they're a bad idea](http://rield.com/faq/why-url-shorteners-are-bad).

Comment: @Ben - Waiting for a logo makes sense, but it could be months or even longer until the site is out of beta. At bicycles, we're going on 274 days in beta, and no word on when the site will be finalized, despite obvious growth and encouragement from the SE folks. Wait for the "real" site and this one may never make it our of beta. Tee-shirts now!

Comment: Heh, I was not advocating the idea, just putting it out there.  Nothing to disagree with.

Comment: Using a short URL also would take away branding and it would probably would take away from the remember-ability of the link.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a joke, what about something like that:

[image: You're talking to me?]

Comment: this is AWESOME !!

Comment: Hahahahaha Scherzissimo!!

Comment: Wha about something like that: http://lostinthecloud.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/faeries-aire.gif  
http://indianapublicmedia.org/arts/files/2011/03/faeries4.jpg  
http://www.roumazeilles.net/news/fr/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/wbm.jpg

Comment: Very complicated, but I really like it **because** of that

Answer (score 2):

The front:

[image]

(Maybe the front logo could be small, located where a pocket would be.)

The back:

[image]

(I've used a slogan I proposed [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/flyers-for-people-to-use) for a flyer. It's not oficial or anything, but it may start conversations.)

Comment: this will be really cute to be placed in front as a small logo.

Comment: If you are a programmer and a musician, you would call this mark a stackoverflow question :)

Comment: I tried doing it with the up- and down-voting triangles, but it's too busy then. Simple is good, IMO.