# I'm going to print up some flyers to distribute at music colleges

Tags: discussion

Based on one of the entries in [this question on what our logo should look like](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/104), I have decided to try and actively target music colleges in Scotland with flyers that will look like this:

[image]

This is my first draft, with the wording taken directly from the help page - can I ask for your thoughts, guidance, improvements.

I will alter spacing, and arrange a valid QR code etc., but figured I'd get input from the community first.

Comment: Looks nice. I would suggest a more intriguing typographical hierarchy so it isn't so bland and boxy.

Comment: What do you reckon, a more script like font for the text, like the title?

Comment: Perhaps a more laid-back Sans or a Roman.

Answer (score 9):

Great idea! I would recommend making the QR code out of a Bit.ly link or equivalent so you can track the number of snaps.

Typography-wise, pursuant to Luke's comment, I would probably use the SE default of 'Helvetica Neue'. You could spice up the main body by bolding key phrases.

I prefer the wording of `musical practice, performance...` instead of `music practice, performance...`.

I would also try to make an impact of sorts by having a big "Q&A" displayed somewhere... oh heck, now I've gone and made my own. **[SOURCE MATERIAL](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bn33h5nzwij42sw/layMflyRs9)**

[image: Poster]

Comment: From past experience, grayscale watermarks can look quite nice even when mass-printing on a laser printer, but you may have to play with the darkness of the watermark a little bit until you find the right balance for your printer.

Comment: Good thinking to make it completely gray-scale. Color printing can get expensive.

Comment: Right, and I didn't think the "Beta" aspect is really important to the effort.

Comment: That's pretty nice! I was hoping others were more artistic than me:-)

Comment: Good note from Tim Post - suggests making the QR code go to the About page, to help educate new visitors!

Comment: This looks pretty good! One thing we noticed, though, was that "Q&A" kinda got lost there. It looks more like a background rather than something that's a part of the header. The header looks a bit hard to read as a result, cause my brain keeps trying to make sense of it because I know Q&A is supposed to be a part of it, but... [do I read it first? do I ignore it? Halp!](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-VFz_r7ZLPhM/UR4ZlTBU6sI/AAAAAAAABTc/DOLSq7l--g4/s320/The_Walking_Dead_Season_1_Meme_Rick_Hospital_Sign_DeadShed.jpg) (cc @DrMayhem)

Comment: Hahahaha - thanks @AnnaLear - will try a couple of edits. Maybe remove the Q&A watermark altogether - I'll try and print off one or two to see what they look like

Comment: Is "Music Stack Exchange" the site's nickname? It results in a temptation to hyphenate "students"...

Comment: @searchfgold6789 - no, it is actually the site's real name