# Triangle fermata vote buttons

Tags: discussion

Why did the triangle fermata voting buttons get removed?

Reminded by the comments here [Triangle above note, with dot in it](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/43287/25111)

Comment: This happened when SE moved away from personalisation of every graduated site and just kept minor customisations. The workload to maintain all the individual configs was significant. I can't remember exactly when.

Comment: We had triangle-fermata vote buttons? That's awesome and sorry to have missed out on 
that. That plus time-signature-font vote totals would be even better.

Comment: You can see images of our old design, including those buttons, [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/music-se-site-design-with-an-updated-logo-and-color). I'd forgotten about it until Dom reminded me a year or so ago!

Comment: I have this strange feeling I've seen it at some point... Maybe at least 3 years ago.

Comment: Here's a link to that same question on the Wayback Machine, 2 days after it was asked, with the old voting button: https://web.archive.org/web/20160408183907/http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/triangle-above-note-with-dot-in-it