# Can we customize the checkmark for accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

Now with the new design a lot of elements on the site have become more music-like. I particularly like the note glyphs for the badges. The [upvote and downvote buttons were discussed and voted on](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92/what-should-our-logo-and-site-design-look-like), but the green checkmark for accepted answers looks like some default implementation.

Looking at the design for other sites like gaming.SE who have a pixelated checkmark

[image]

and rpg.SE who have a shielded one

[image]

makes me think we can do better than what we have. I'm not a graphical designer, but *if* there is an option to stylize them, should't we?

Answer (score 3):

It already is - the design includes a customised check mark, that is different from other graduated sites, and matches the other icons:

[image]

Comment: Looks very standard and not in line with the music theme, but if you say so...

Comment: @user1803551 It matches the whole site design; not everything has to be exactly in line with the music theme. It would be like a person wearing jean trousers, jean jacket, jean shirt and to top it off, jean boots

Comment: It would be really funny if we made it look like this: 